# Generate a Constant expression from a function

Tags: java, google-wave

For my Google Wave robot, on the onDocumentChanged event I want to apply a filter as follows:

```
@Capability(filter = FILTER)
@Override
public void onDocumentChanged(DocumentChangedEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

I want the filter to be generated the first time the robot is run, which I'm trying to do as follows:

```
private static final String FILTER = generateFilter();

private static final String generateFilter(){
    ...
}
```

However, it complains FILTER isn't a constant expression when used within @Capability.

generateFilter() will return the same string every time it is called, I'm only using it to create the string so that when I make changes, I don't need to worry about updating the filter.

Now I could be going about this all wrong, so wondered if anyone knew what I'm doing wrong, or knew a better way in which I could generate a constant expression from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Google Wave, but a [*static initializer*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7) might be acceptable, as shown [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) and outlined below.

```
private static final String FILTER;
static { FILTER = "..."; }
```

Addendum: On closer scrutiny, this approach is *not* possible, as an [*annotation value*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7) must be (among other things) a [*constant expression*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs the contant value in the annotation at compile time and your initialization will happen i think at the application initialization time.

You could probably do it like this:

```
private static final String FILTER = "YOUR STRING";

private static final String generateFilter() {
   return FILTER;
}
```

That way if you need to change it and not worry you will go the the method and from there to the constant value :).